# On analytic local manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory

I'm studiyng some properties about analytic local (p-adic) manifolds. I'm using the only reference that i found (Number Theory of Shafarevich and Borevich).
Do you know if there are other references where i can understand better this argument? I'm  particularly interested about other proofs of two theorems of the Shafarevich's book.

Theorem 1: If $V$ is a not trivial local anayltic manifold, $V$ contains some curve.

Theorem 2: If $V,V'$ are two manifolds and $V \not \subset V'$ there is a curve of $V$ whitout points of $V'$.